# Python's subprocess with "1>&2" and stderr=STDOUT

Tags: python, subprocess

I have this code from https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/

I'm not sure how to interpret the code, in the `check_output` with `1>&2` output is redirected to stderr, but in the parameter, the stderr is back to stdout `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.

```
output = subprocess.check_output(
    'echo to stdout; echo to stderr 1>&2; exit 1',
    shell=True,  
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, 
    )
print "*****************"
print 'Have %d bytes in output' % len(output)
print output
```

Running the code, the print commands are not executed meaning nothing is captured.

What does this code trying to accomplish?

### EDIT

From the answer and comment, I could run this code to get

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(
        'echo to stdout; echo to stderr 1>&2; exit 1',
        shell=True,  # No such file or directory error without, maybe 1>&2 requires shell=True
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,  
        )

except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:

    print "*****************"
    print 'Have %d bytes in output' % len(e.output)
    print e.output
```

this output:

```
*****************
Have 20 bytes in output
to stdout
to stderr
```

However, when I commented out the `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` line, I got instead

```
to stderr
*****************
Have 10 bytes in output
to stdout
```

#### EDIT2

I tested more with stderr library (https://github.com/sickill/stderred) that helps a shell to show characters from stderr in red color.

When I execute this code (comment out the redirection), I can see the `to stderr` in BLACK color which implies it uses stdout.

```
output = subprocess.check_output(
        'echo to stdout; echo to stderr 1>&2; exit 1',
        shell=True,  
        #stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, 
        )
```

From this, I guess (correct me if I'm wrong) that Python's `check_output` method prints out the data into the stderr redirect to stdout so that it prints out the error message into stderr.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `1 >&2` shell code applies only to the (echo) command it appears on.  It is how to tell the shell to direct the output of that echo to the shell's stderr stream.

The python code `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` tells the subprocess module that you want the process's stderr stream to be the same file descriptor as its stdout stream so that you will read whatever the process writes to either stream interleaved together in one stream.

The `exit 1` in the shell command means that the shell exits with an error (non-zero) status.

The purpose of the code is to demonstrate that the python function [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) will check the exit status and raise an exception when it is non-zero.

> If the exit code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError. The CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode attribute and output in the output attribute.

Your description of:

> Running the code, the print commands are not executed

is a bit misleading since you neglect to mention the output that does occur:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 6, in <module>
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'echo to stdout; echo to stderr 1>&2; exit 1' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: I got the same output even when I removed all the three print commands, so I'm pretty sure that the print commands are *not* executed.

Comment: @prosseek: yes, if the exception is happens then unless you catch it; the `print` statements are not executed that is how exceptions work -- they interrupt the normal flow of the program. You could add `try: check_output(...) except CalledProcessError as e: print('exception: %s, captured output: %s' % (e, e.output))`